# mongodb and node js embeded query how to use

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have this this schema for my users. users can store more then one address now my question is that how i can push embed data object of address in users collection after he register.

```
var address = new Schema({
    city            : { type: String },
    delivery_area   : {type: String },
    address_title   : { type: String }

});

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    f_name : String,
    l_name : String,
    gender : String,
    email_address : String,
    dob : { type : Date},
    password : String,
    device_type : String,
    reg_id : String,
    addresses :[address]
});

var User = mongoose.model("Users", UserSchema);
```

this is code i use to save a user but actual problem is now how i can push the multiple address for a user

```
var a = new users(req.body); 
a.save(function(err, row){});
```

Comment: how are you creating an address for the user?

Comment: it's  api. im hitting in post man.

Answer (score 0):

There is [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) method to add new item into array.

Just use it with mongoose like this :

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(id, {$push: 'addresses': {city:'something'}})
```

Comment: i hope it should work. in id place i will use _id im going to update libik?

Comment: Yes, just read docs abot $push in mongoDB and about findOneAndUpdate of mongoose, there is description of all parameters.